# Oracle Alter User Not Working With PowerShell

Tags: oracle, powershell, odac

I am trying to use PowerShell to change Oracle accounts. The .net DLL does not seem to support Oracle SQL that contains Alter User command. I am getting the following output/error:

```sql
Trying to connect to Database instance on NIMHDDEV...Success.
SELECT  ALL_USERS
SYS
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Below is the PowerShell for testing.

- a select statement that works
- an alter statement that does not work

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient")
```

```bsh
$objOracleConnection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection 
$ds="Data Source=$ServerName; User ID=$login; Password=$password; Integrated Security=No" 
$objOracleConnection.ConnectionString = $ds
Write-Host "Trying to connect to Database instance on $ServerName..." -NoNewline
$objOracleConnection.Open()
Write-Host "Success."

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ALL_USERS" 
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($sql, $objOracleConnection)
$cmd.ExecuteScalar()    


$sql = 'ALTER USER Account unlock'
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($sql, $objOracleConnection)
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Does `$PasswordNew` possibly contain a double-quote (`"`)?

Comment: both the login and the password only contain letters and numbers.

Comment: I removed my answer since you replaced it with an example that does not take input into account, and it was no longer relevant. Not sure why `alter user` isn't working for you but do note that the [System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) namespace is deprecated, and it is recommended to use a third-party solution with Oracle databases.